# Custom Route implementation and ChildAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have a custom route implementation for make url segments lowered and dashed like this:

```
/Home/About -> /home/about/
/MyDocs/MyPage/23 -> /my-docs/my-pages/23/
```

and so on. It was working and I have used it in several projects without any problem until I decide to switch to `MVC 4`. In new project, normal actions work correctly. But I have problem to call `Html.Action` or `Html.RenderAction`. e.g. for `MyDocsController.MyChild` it can not find the controller (`my-docs`) or for `MydocsController.MyChild` it finds controller (`mydocs`) but can not find action (`my-child`). Is there any diferences between `MVC 3` and `MVC 4` routing? Why it works in `MVC 3` but not in `MVC 4`?

Comment: can you show the sample code where you are using `Html.Action` and `Html.RenderAction`

Comment: Do you mean `@Html.Action("action", "controller")` or `@{ Html.RenderAction("action", "controller"); }` or the action method?

Comment: in what ever way you are using it however i have used it by the first method you have described in the comments and its working just fine, clean the solution and build again or make a new project and see if it works just to make sure that your current projects structure is intact

Comment: I did all your suggestions. I have created project 4 times! and everything seems OK, But is not. I'm confused.

Comment: hmmm something is going real bad, sorry pal cant help you out at the moment, if your problem is not resolved after 8 hrs(that is when ill be home after work :) ) i sure will investigate your scenario... tc